# Stateful Session Bean lifecycle

Tags: ejb-3.0, cart, stateful-session-bean

I have a "stateful session bean" that initializes a synchronizedList,i add products to the list and check the list, it works(all during the same session).
Is it normal that when I do the "undeploy" of my application and then make another"deploy" I lose all the saved data of my bean?

Answer (score 0):

It is desired behavior, just imagine what might happen to created SFSB if I would change collection type from list to map and redeploy app.

Actually hot deploy feature is out scope of EJB specification, so session beans might behave differently depending of witch application server you use. For example in weblogic 8 after redeploy of any type of app module, all SFSBeans referefences are lost (stubs are discarded).

Personally I prefer to restart production server after hot deploy, as there always might be some memory leaks (caused by previous classloaders).

Comment: thank you for your answers but my bean does not retain data neither when i restart the browser.. I think I should make another question